# react facing issues to find out specific data from an array of objects

Tags: reactjs, json

I have a few collections of data that are in JSON format and want to access specific data conditional data, an example I want to access which one has teacher:true and put it in a state.
I have tried it with conditions inside the loop and filter function.

```
[
  0:{name:"Rou",id:"121"}
  1:{name:"Sou",id:"122",teacher:"true"}
  2:{name:"Tou",id:"123"}
  3:{name:"Vou",id:"124",teacher:"true"}
  4:{name:"Kou",id:"125",teacher:"false"}
  5:{name:"Wou",id:"126"}
]
```

here I want to get only

```
 1:{name:"Sou",id:"122",teacher:"true"}
 3:{name:"Vou",id:"124",teacher:"true"}
```

which means only where the teacher is true.

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with react. It's a javascript array problem.

```js
let people = [
  {name:"Rou",id:"121"},
  {name:"Sou",id:"122",teacher:"true"},
  {name:"Tou",id:"123"},
  {name:"Vou",id:"124",teacher:"true"},
  {name:"Kou",id:"125",teacher:"false"},
  {name:"Wou",id:"126"}
];

let teachers = people.filter((person) => person.teacher == "true");
```

Note that you need it's strongly recommended to use a boolean type instead of a string:

```
// Strongly discouraged
{name:"Sou",id:"122",teacher:"true"};

// Better
{name:"Sou",id:"122",teacher: true};
```

Comment: Ok, thanks for your suggestion. I have another problem that is, you have solved the problem and got two users data, then how should get data from another table of those two users, or can be more users, I mean how can I fetch data from another table using these users Id.

Comment: for example, I have got two persons data which has teacher:true and id 122, 124, by using these id's and teacher:true how should get these perticular persons data from another table, example like --- let infoDetails= [{name:"Rou",id:"121", email:"rou@rou.com"},{name:"Sou",id:"122",teacher:"true", email:"sou@sou.com"},{name:"Tou",id:"123"},
  {name:"Vou",id:"124",teacher:"true", email:"tou@tou.com"},{name:"Kou",id:"125",teacher:"false",email:"kou@kou.com"}]; from this table

Comment: `let ids = ["122", "124"]; let teachers = people.filter((person) => person.teacher == "true" && ids.includes(person.id));`

Comment: thank you, but I mean for more than two IDs or uncountable.